# React won't pass a particular value to "props"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a strange issue that I can't pin down with React (I'm using CoffeeScript as well, but I highly doubt this is a factor). Basically, I'm following along with a tutorial in which a message feed is built using a Feed component (the parent), FeedList component (child), and a FeedItem (grandchild)...sorry if my terminology is incorrect. The relevant code is:

Feed.cjsx

```
getInitialState: ->
  FEED_ITEMS = [
    { key: 1, title: 'Realtime data!', description: 'Firebase is cool', voteCount: 49 }
    { key: 2, title: 'JavaScript is fun', description: 'Lexical scoping FTW', voteCount: 34 }
    { key: 3, title: 'Coffee makes you awake', description: 'Drink responsibly', voteCount: 15 }
  ]
  {
    items: FEED_ITEMS
    formDisplayed: false
  }
  ...

render: ->
  ...
  <FeedList items={@state.items} onVote={@onVote} />
```

FeedList.cjsx

```
render: ->

  feedItems = @props.items.map ((item) -> 
    <FeedItem key={item.key} ... />
  ).bind(@)

  <ul className='list-group container'>
    {feedItems}
  </ul>
```

FeedItem.cjsx

```
render: ->
  <li key={@props.key} className='list-group-item'>
    ...
  </li>
```

If I console.log "@props.key" in the render method for FeedItem, I get undefined. But if I log "item.key" from inside the map function of FeedList's render method, I get 1, 2, 3, as I should. So it seems to me that, for whatever reason, React doesn't want to pass the "key" prop to the FeedItem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since react treats key as a special attribute (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/special-non-dom-attributes.html), it cannot be accessed via the props. The react documentation also warns against setting keys within plain html tags (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children), and suggests wrapping multiple components in a react component.

If you rename `key` to something  non-reserved, it should work:

Feed.cjsx:

```
FEED_ITEMS = [
    { itemId: 1, title: 'Realtime data!', description: 'Firebase is cool', voteCount: 49 }
    { itemId: 2, title: 'JavaScript is fun', description: 'Lexical scoping FTW', voteCount: 34 }
    { itemId: 3, title: 'Coffee makes you awake', description: 'Drink responsibly', voteCount: 15 }
]
```

then you can access the itemId via `@props.itemId` in the child component (FeedList).

FeedList:

```
feedItems = @props.items.map ((item) -> 
    <FeedItem key={item.itemId} ... />
).bind(@)
```

Note that the keys for each component need to be unique for each component, or node in the DOM, which is why it makes sense that keys cannot be inherited, as setting both parent and child to the same key would not allow react to identify them as separate entities when rendering the DOM.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond but I just freed up enough at work to revisit this problem. I'm still having this issue. I understand that React treats key as a special attribute, but in my FEED_ITEMS object array, "key" is used to set the key attribute that React expects. Sorry if that sounds confusing, but when I change "key" to "itemId," as you have suggested, I get this warning: "Each child in an array should have a unique 'key' prop." When I keep it as "key," the warning goes away but then the buttons are broken.

Comment: You still need to set a key when using `map`.  This key can be set to the ItemId.  The answer has been updated to show this.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! I've been attending some React workshops for the past few weeks and I think I'm getting the hang of this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else stumbling across this, react only has a few reserved props but they are worth noting. key, ref, __self and __source.

`var RESERVED_PROPS = {
  key: true,
  ref: true,
  __self: true,
  __source: true
};`

^^ Taken from the react source.

Also worth noting `__self={this}` is really useful if you're receiving invariant violation errors and would like to be able to debug them down to a component level.

Comment: Great callout. Thanks for sharing!